# Reading a BZ2 file line by line

Tags: perl

I'd like to read a file line by line like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', "file.txt" or die "Can't read file.txt: $!";

while (<$fh>) {

}
close $fh;
```

but I cannot find how to do this for compressed files, like bz2 and gz.

I can't understand from the [documentation for `IO::Uncompress::Bunzip2`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/Bunzip2.html#read)
how I can implement this in a real program.

How can I read a compressed file line by line as I do above for normal files?

Comment: `while ( $line = $z->getline())`

Comment: Errr have you actually tried this?

Comment: @Jens that only prints the binary code.

Comment: @AhmedMasud I've tried numerous "solutions" which don't print the lines.  Perhaps you could be more specific?

Comment: @con: I think you need to show the code that you have tried and isn't working for you, as well as describing in detail the problems that arose. There is no point in getting so enraged (I have moderated your language to get you some answers) and we can't really tell you much more than the documentation says without at least *some* information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Uncompress::Bunzip2 '$Bunzip2Error';

my $file = "somefile.txt.bz2";

my $zh = IO::Uncompress::Bunzip2->new( $file, {
    AutoClose   => 1,
    Transparent => 1,
} ) or die "IO::Uncompress::Bunzip2 failed: $Bunzip2Error\n";

while ( <$zh> ) {
    print;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about `$input`, is this a hash or a string? `Global symbol "%input" requires explicit package name at get_labels.pl line 7.`

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile as it was. I've fixed that and a couple of other issues.

Comment: @con: `$input` is defined in the program. It's just a simple string.

Comment: @borodin I just typed it out was going to fix it and got distracted by something else, thanks for the fix!

Comment: @Borodin thank you very much, I've accepted your answer.

Comment: @AhmedMasud: Don't post it first and then test and fix it afterwards!

Comment: @con: Neither `AutoClose` nor `Transparent` are necessary for this to work. You can safely use just `my $zh = IO::Uncompress::Bunzip2->new( $input )`

Comment: @AhmedMasud: You don't appear to know whatb you're talking about. As **choroba** commented above, it is *indirect object syntax* that is bad practice, which is `new IO::Uncompress::Bunzip2`. `AutoClose` and `Transparent` are unnecessary; you are showing someone *how to do* something, not writing a finished program. Together with the `bunzip2` import they really cloud your code. And I changed your variable names because they were dreadful.

Comment: @con: It's not my answer unfortunately.